# How to use values from range input into if statement with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, input, range

I have a slider that can change volume. I also have a button that raises the `count` variable by 1 every time it's clicked.

I wrote an `if`-statement which should give an alert if those two variables match but it's not working.

```
if ($scope.count == $scope.data.volume) {
   alert('finished')
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNrOgm)

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your If statement it's out of the plusOne function

```
$scope.plusOne = function() {
    $scope.count++
}
if ($scope.count == $scope.data.volume) {
    alert('finished')
}
```

it will not work until you include

```
$scope.plusOne = function() {
   $scope.count++
   if ($scope.count == $scope.data.volume) {
      alert('finished')
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the fact that the range slider could change the value of data.volume

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted on codepen (posted here, because the code you posted in your question doesn't provide enough context);

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.myTitle = 'Template';
    $scope.data = { 'volume' : '5' };
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.plusOne = function() {
      $scope.count++
    }
    if ($scope.count == $scope.data.volume) {
      alert('finished')
    } 
  });
```

You are only checking if `$scope.count == $scope.data.volume` once, when the controller is instantiated. Your code doesn't account for the fact that you need to do the check when the values actually change too. You'll need to use `$scope.$watchCollection`.

If using Angular > 1.2 (and it looks like you are from your codepen)...

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[count,data.volume]',function() {
  if ($scope.count == $scope.data.volume) {
    alert('finished')
  }
});
```

Note, that first parameter to `$scope.$watchCollection` is *not* an array - it's a string that sort of looks like an array.